# Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter error in a while loop

Tags: php, mysql

Im creating a simple mailing list with check boxes for each email listed. how ever it throws out an error when I try and put it into a form.

PHP

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
require '../database/connect.php';

echo "<h1>Mailing list</h1>";


$mailcount = 0;
$namecount = 0;

$get = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cliet_data WHERE send = 1");
echo "<form action='send.php' method='get'>";
while ($getrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($get)){
    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='mail_'".$mailcount." value='".$getrow['email']."' CHECKED <br/>".$getrow['name'].">";
}

echo "</form>";

?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I guess that `cliet_data` should be `client_data`

Comment: Do not use `mysql_*` functions as they are deprecated. Learn how to use prepared statements with mysqli or PDO

Comment: plz manually run "SELECT * FROM cliet_data WHERE send = 1" query in query editor then see output.

Answer (score 0):

Use
 like

```
 if(mysql_num_rows($get) > 0)
{

  while ($getrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($get)){
    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='mail_'".$mailcount." value='".$getrow['email']."'      CHECKED <br/>".$getrow['name'].">";
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

cliet_data should be `client_data`.

Your MySQL request is wrong, so it returns false.

Answer (score 0):

This issue about mysql_query returning `False`. At first check result exist or not.

If you get `No result`, check for sql query.

```
$get = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cliet_data WHERE send = 1");

if (!$get){
   // No result
} else {
    echo "<form action='send.php' method='get'>";
    while ($getrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($get)) {
        echo "<input type='checkbox' name='mail_'".$mailcount." value='".$getrow['email']."' CHECKED <br/>".$getrow['name'].">";
    }
}
```

Comment: ,you sir are a legend.. thanks alot, for got about my if else statement.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for a table I have on my db. Just make sure the result is not empty. And also, check for the typo - **cliet_data**

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
require '../database/connect.php';

echo "<h1>Mailing list</h1>";


$mailcount = 0;
$namecount = 0;

$get = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cliet_data WHERE send = 1");
if (mysql_num_rows($get)>0) {
    echo "<form action='send.php' method='get'>";
    while ($getrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($get)){
        echo "<input type='checkbox' name='mail_'".$mailcount." value='".$getrow['email']."' CHECKED <br/>".$getrow['name'].">";
    }

    echo "</form>";
}
?>
```